# Getting an “Undefined constant '__NAMESPACE__'” error in PhpStorm even after a namespace has been defined

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am completely new to PHP and I am trying to teach myself here and play with the prospect of creating my very own WordPress theme - YAY!

Anyway, I am running into a roadblock here and I am not certain if this is just the IDE I am using (PhpStorm), or if it is something else.

Here is what I am seeing in PhpStorm:

[image]

When I use Kint, it shows that the namespace is defined as shown in the screenshot above (namespace SavvyPro\Sandbox):

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
namespace SavvyPro\Sandbox;

add_action('loop_start', __NAMESPACE__ . '\process_the_string');
function process_the_string()
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    render_user_message($current_user->user_firstname, get_the_ID());
}

function render_user_message($first_name, $post_id)
{
    d("My name is {$first_name}.");

    ddd("The post ID is {$post_id}.");
}
```

Here is the version of PhpStorm I am currently running:

[image]

I am certain it is something quite simple for you PHP gurus out there, but since I am such a noob, it's a bit of a brain twister for me.

Any help on this is of course greatly appreciated.

Thank you all!

Comment: In PHPStorm you can setup the PHP version of your project to adjust the warnings. Maybe your version is set prior to php 5.3, where \__NAMESPACE__ didn't exist?

Comment: 1) What is your PhpStorm version? 2) What is PHP Language Level set in IDE for this project? 3) Did you upgrade PhpStorm (had older version in the past) .. or that's a brand new fresh install?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the version of PhpStorm I was running. I edited my original post and added that. I wasn't aware of any Language Level. I will check on that. Thanks for your help fellas, appreciate it.

Comment: @IAmSirAskAlot For some reason some users (yeah only some) of 2020.2.x are facing this weird issue where IDE does not recognize standard PHP functions/classes/constants etc (still no solid idea on why only some are affected). You need to manually delete some caches/indexes while IDE is closed (worked for everybody thus far who faced it) -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54626 for details

Comment: @LazyOne, that's what I just did and it fixed my issue. BTW, it was JetBrains that got back to me regarding this fix and I resolved it just yesterday and just now wanted to post the fix here and saw your response. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed JetBrains support and they got back to me with the fix and it is exactly what @LazyOne mentioned in the comments section above.

I simply deleted the following folder on my Mac and it resolved the issue:

***~Library/Caches/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2***

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue with later versions of PHPStorm.  I just had to delete this folder to fix this very same issue with 2022.3.1 -

**~Library/Caches/JetBrains/PhpStorm2022.3**